# How do i map int values in PHP from one range to another

Tags: php

I have an interger which can range from 24 to 0, i'm looking for  a way to map this value to produce an int in a range which is from 10 to 0 in PHP.

Comment: You have got to give us more details than this. Map how?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Perhaps with an example of what you try to achieve. It's hard to understand your question as it is now